# Jenkins virtualbox plugin failed to launch agent

Tags: jenkins, virtualbox, jenkins-plugins

I used the fork on Github to get the virtualbox plugin which supports VirtualBox 5.1.6. After installed the plugin and configured the node, I clicked the launch button to set the agent online, During the launch process, it did run the virtualbox, but it always failed to set the agent online. The log is shown below.

I have Jenkins ver. 2.89.2 and virtualbox 5.1.6

```
[VirtualBox] Launching node Automatic Test setup
[VirtualBox] Powering up VirtualBoxMachine{host=VirtualBoxHost{url='http://10.1.20.81:18083', username=''},name='Automatic Test setup'}...
[VirtualBox] node Automatic Test setup in state Running
[VirtualBox] node Automatic Test setup started
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 1
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 2
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 3
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 4
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 5
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 6
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 7
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 8
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 9
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 10
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed
[VirtualBox] Sleep before stage 2 launcher, attempt 11
[VirtualBox] Starting stage 2 launcher (JNLPLauncher)
[VirtualBox] Stage 2 launcher completed 
[VirtualBox] Maximum number of attempts reached
```